# AngularJS not getting activated when loading HTML from script

Tags: angularjs

I have this scenario, I am loading part of HTML (which has AngularJS directives) dynamically via script and I see AngularJS is not getting activated.

here is the example I am looking at. Is there anyway I can tell AngularJS to start bind on document ready? Loading an aspx page containing this widget1 content via a iframe seems to work but I am trying to avoid iframe and use client side script. 
Appreciate any help.

```
<body ng-app>
main content page
<br />
<!-- widget1 -->
<b>Widget1</b>
<div id="widget1">
    <!-- load below div via jquery/or any method from a remote html file-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("div#widget1").load("/widgetsfolder/widget1.htm");
    </script>
</div>
```

widget.htm file has below content.

```
   <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        Total todo items: {{getTotalItems()}}
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" />
                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}} </span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

my controller code below.

```
`function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.totalItems = 4;
    debugger;
    $scope.todos = [{
        text: 'learn angularjs',
        done: false
    }, {
        text: 'implement angularjs',
        done: false
    }, {
        text: 'something else',
        done: false
    }, ];
```

$scope.getTotalItems = function () {
    return $scope.todos.length;
}

}`

sample code here
http://jsfiddle.net/devs/RGfp4/

Answer (score 2):

Apero's answer describes what is going on. I believe you are going to want to use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude). Your html would look something like this:

```
<body ng-app>
    main content page
    <br />
    <!-- widget1 -->
    <b>Widget1</b>
    <div ng-include="'/widgetsfolder/widget1.htm'">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS evaluates the scope and renders the page after it is loaded.

Here, your js script loads the widget html but after Angular already compiled the scope etc.

I believe this will not work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angulars ngINclude to fetch outside documents, but I don't suggest it, it can be buggy. You can get the partials using either $http or $resource, this will fetch the data and compile the angular directives inside.

If you want to load the script using some other method, you can store the data as a string inside the controller and use a $compile directive in order to execute the angular code inside it.